# Ask user if they wish to continue

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods, do-while

I put together a program which plays tic tac toe on the command line but I want to add a feature which once the game is complete, it asks the user if they want to play again and if they enter Y then it plays again and if they enter N its breaks but I'm not sure where to start the do while loop and where to close it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test3
{
static int A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3;

static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args)
{
System.out.println();
System.out.println();

  String prompt = "Welcome to our X and O's game . Please take your first go: ";
    String playerMove = "";
    String cpuMove = "";
    boolean gameIsDecided = false;

   for (int i = 1; i <=9; i++)
    {
        //Gives the human player its identity(1) and sets out what happens if player wins

        playerMove = getMove(prompt);
        updateBoard(playerMove, 1);
        displayBoard();
        if (isGameDecided())
        {
            System.out.println("Congratulations , you have beaten me!!");
            gameIsDecided = true;
            break;
        }

      if (i < 9)
        {
            cpuMove = getCpuMove();
            System.out.println(cpuMove);
            updateBoard(cpuMove, 2);
            displayBoard();
            if (isGameDecided())
            {
                System.out.println("Unlucky , I win. Better luck next time :");
                gameIsDecided = true;
                break;
            }
            prompt = "Take your next go: ";
            i++;
        }
    }
    if (!gameIsDecided)
        System.out.println("So nothing can separate us , the game is a draw !!");
}

       public static String getMove(String prompt)
{
    String turn;
    System.out.print(prompt);
    do
    {
        turn = sc.nextLine();
        if (!isAcceptablePlay(turn))
        {
            System.out.println("Unfortunately this move isn't valid , please try again !!");
        }
    } while (!isAcceptablePlay(turn));
    return turn;
}

     public static boolean isAcceptablePlay(String turn)
{
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("A1") & A1 == 0)
        return true;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("A2") & A2 == 0)
        return true;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("A3") & A3 == 0)
        return true;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("B1") & B1 == 0)
        return true;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("B2") & B2 == 0)
        return true;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("B3") & B3 == 0)
        return true;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("C1") & C1 == 0)
        return true;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("C2") & C2 == 0)
        return true;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("C3") & C3 == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}

   public static void updateBoard(String turn, int player)
{
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("A1"))
        A1 = player;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("A2"))
        A2 = player;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("A3"))
        A3 = player;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("B1"))
        B1 = player;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("B2"))
        B2 = player;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("B3"))
        B3 = player;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("C1"))
        C1 = player;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("C2"))
        C2 = player;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("C3"))
        C3 = player;
}


    public static void displayBoard()
{
    String row = "";
    System.out.println();

    row = " " + getSymbol(A1) + " | " + getSymbol(A2) + " | " + getSymbol(A3);
    System.out.println(row);
    System.out.println("-----------");

    row = " " + getSymbol(B1) + " | " + getSymbol(B2) + " | " + getSymbol(B3);
    System.out.println(row);
    System.out.println("-----------");

    row = " " + getSymbol(C1) + " | " + getSymbol(C2) + " | " + getSymbol(C3);
    System.out.println(row);
    System.out.println();
}

  public static String getSymbol(int square)
{
    if (square == 1)
        return "X";
    if (square == 2)
        return "O";
    return " ";
}
//This controls the Computer move . By mixing them up we make the computer more competitive
public static String getCpuMove()
{
    if (B2 == 0)
        return  "B2";

    if (A3 == 0)
        return  "A3";

    if (C2 == 0)
        return  "C2";

    if (B1 == 0)
        return  "B1";

    if (B3 == 0)
        return  "B3";

    if (C1 == 0)
        return  "C1";

    if (A1 == 0)
        return "A1";

    if (C3 == 0)
        return  "C3";
    if (A2 == 0)
        return "A2";
    return "";
}

//This contains all the possible winning combinations .
public static boolean isGameDecided()
{
    if (is3inARow(A1, A2, A3))
        return true;
    if (is3inARow(B1, B2, B3))
        return true;
    if (is3inARow(C1, C2, C3))
        return true;
    if (is3inARow(A1, B1, C1))
        return true;
    if (is3inARow(A2, B2, C2))
        return true;
    if (is3inARow(A3, B3, C3))
        return true;
    if (is3inARow(A1, B2, C3))
        return true;
    if (is3inARow(A3, B2, C1))
        return true;
    return false;
}

public static boolean is3inARow(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return ((a == b) & (a == c) & (a != 0));
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you can code it yourself, so I'm not going to give you the code, but just some guidelines.

First don't write most of the game in the main method, put it into it's own method. Maybe call that method "play" and call it from the main method. Then when play() finishes, add a win() call right below it in the main method. When the game calls win(), print to the console if the user wants to play again. Then add:

```
if (input.equals("Y")) {
    play();
}
```

You don't need an else because otherwise the program will break and that is what you want.

You could use a do while loop, but that would be unnecessary and more complicated in my opinion.

Comment: Just the right amount of info in my opinion.

Comment: That is actually another thread which i put up on here , I recognised that using one java file is not the right way to go about it , but I'm struggling to divide this up into separate classes which i can call from the main java file

Comment: @Arran well you could go about having separate class files, but even just having separate methods will do. In fact if it's troubling you putting it in separate class files, methods are the way to go. It's not terrible to have long class files, especially when it's a pretty simplistic process. However, if you want to call methods from another class in your main class, the method has to be `static`. You can call like this: `ClassName.someMethod()`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can only do a big edit

```
int main(...)
{ 
    char exit = 'N';
    do {
        //your code here        
    exit = System.in.read();
    } while(exit != 'Y');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test3
{
static int A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3;

static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new test3().starttPlaying();

}


    String prompt = "Welcome to our X and O's game . Please take your first go: ";
    String playerMove = "";
    String cpuMove = "";
    boolean gameIsDecided = false;


    public void starttPlaying(){
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    boolean playAgain = true;

        while (playAgain) {            


   for (int i = 1; i <=9; i++)
    {
        //Gives the human player its identity(1) and sets out what happens if player wins

        playerMove = getMove(prompt);
        updateBoard(playerMove, 1);
        displayBoard();
        if (isGameDecided())
        {
            System.out.println("Congratulations , you have beaten me!!");
            gameIsDecided = true;
            break;
        }

      if (i < 9)
        {
            cpuMove = getCpuMove();
            System.out.println(cpuMove);
            updateBoard(cpuMove, 2);
            displayBoard();
            if (isGameDecided())
            {
                System.out.println("Unlucky , I win. Better luck next time :");
                gameIsDecided = true;
                break;
            }
            prompt = "Take your next go: ";
            i++;
        }
    }
   if (!gameIsDecided)
      System.out.println("So nothing can separate us , the game is a draw !!");

        System.out.println("do you want to play Again Y : N"); 
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       String desicion = scanner.nextLine();
       playAgain = desicion.equalsIgnoreCase("y") ? true : false;
    }
    }


//    



       public static String getMove(String prompt)
{
    String turn;
    System.out.print(prompt);
    do
    {
        turn = sc.nextLine();
        if (!isAcceptablePlay(turn))
        {
            System.out.println("Unfortunately this move isn't valid , please try again !!");
        }
    } while (!isAcceptablePlay(turn));
    return turn;
}

     public static boolean isAcceptablePlay(String turn)
{
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("A1") & A1 == 0)
        return true;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("A2") & A2 == 0)
        return true;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("A3") & A3 == 0)
        return true;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("B1") & B1 == 0)
        return true;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("B2") & B2 == 0)
        return true;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("B3") & B3 == 0)
        return true;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("C1") & C1 == 0)
        return true;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("C2") & C2 == 0)
        return true;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("C3") & C3 == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}

   public static void updateBoard(String turn, int player)
{
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("A1"))
        A1 = player;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("A2"))
        A2 = player;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("A3"))
        A3 = player;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("B1"))
        B1 = player;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("B2"))
        B2 = player;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("B3"))
        B3 = player;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("C1"))
        C1 = player;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("C2"))
        C2 = player;
    if (turn.equalsIgnoreCase("C3"))
        C3 = player;
}


    public static void displayBoard()
{
    String row = "";
    System.out.println();

    row = " " + getSymbol(A1) + " | " + getSymbol(A2) + " | " + getSymbol(A3);
    System.out.println(row);
    System.out.println("-----------");

    row = " " + getSymbol(B1) + " | " + getSymbol(B2) + " | " + getSymbol(B3);
    System.out.println(row);
    System.out.println("-----------");

    row = " " + getSymbol(C1) + " | " + getSymbol(C2) + " | " + getSymbol(C3);
    System.out.println(row);
    System.out.println();
}

  public static String getSymbol(int square)
{
    if (square == 1)
        return "X";
    if (square == 2)
        return "O";
    return " ";
}
//This controls the Computer move . By mixing them up we make the computer more competitive
public static String getCpuMove()
{
    if (B2 == 0)
        return  "B2";

    if (A3 == 0)
        return  "A3";

    if (C2 == 0)
        return  "C2";

    if (B1 == 0)
        return  "B1";

    if (B3 == 0)
        return  "B3";

    if (C1 == 0)
        return  "C1";

    if (A1 == 0)
        return "A1";

    if (C3 == 0)
        return  "C3";
    if (A2 == 0)
        return "A2";
    return "";
}

//This contains all the possible winning combinations .
public static boolean isGameDecided()
{
    if (is3inARow(A1, A2, A3))
        return true;
    if (is3inARow(B1, B2, B3))
        return true;
    if (is3inARow(C1, C2, C3))
        return true;
    if (is3inARow(A1, B1, C1))
        return true;
    if (is3inARow(A2, B2, C2))
        return true;
    if (is3inARow(A3, B3, C3))
        return true;
    if (is3inARow(A1, B2, C3))
        return true;
    if (is3inARow(A3, B2, C1))
        return true;
    return false;
}

public static boolean is3inARow(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return ((a == b) & (a == c) & (a != 0));
}

}
```

i think this is what you are trying to do , try with my code and make more changes if you wish

Comment: This was the issue i was having , i tried that but it doesn't reset the board again when finished so the game becomes unplayable

Comment: tell me how to play this game :D

Comment: 9 square boxes , take it in turns to choose a box and that is marked with X for the user and O for the computer. You have to match 3 in a row to win

Comment: you need to clear the 
`static int A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3;` 
board is updated at the game and once you press yes and game starts again board is not cleared its nothing wrong with my code since you ask how to play the game again ,,clear the board

Comment: with your code , the game does restart , only the positions are still filled . How would i clear them positions though

Comment: yes , thats the problem 
 `Integer a = null;
  A1=a.intValue();` do this to your int variables and clear the board